# How can I get currently used rmw_implementation of running nodes?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to check what rmw_implementation is used for running nodes. Anyone knows how to do it?

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/342573/how-can-i-get-currently-used-rmw_implementation-of-running-nodes?/) by [masat](https://answers.ros.org/users/51247/masat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2020-01-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since the question was asking for "running nodes" you can check which shared libraries that process is using. On Linux you can run:

`lsof -p <PID> | grep rmw`

The list will contain one of the RMW libraries (e.g. `librmw_fastrtps_cpp.so`) beside generic ones like `librmw.so` and `librmw_implementation.so`.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2020-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [masat](https://answers.ros.org/users/51247/masat/) on 2020-02-01**:
Great! That is what I wanted. Thank you Dirk and Steve!